# How to check in ASP.NET MVC View if site is running on localhost or 127.0.0.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to check in ASP.NET MVC View if site is running on localhost or 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the [HttpRequest.IsLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx) Property

Answer (score 26):

```
@if (Request.IsLocal) { // do something }
```

or

```
<% if (Request.IsLocal) { // do something } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
       <% if (Request.Url.DnsSafeHost.Contains("localhost") || Request.UserHostName.Contains("127.0.0.1"))
       {

       } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

for global.asax

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached){themeName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ThemeName"];}
```