# How detect development environment from deployment in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check in ASP.NET MVC View if site is running on localhost or 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209669/how-to-check-in-asp-net-mvc-view-if-site-is-running-on-localhost-or-127-0-0-1)

I am using two entry for connection string in web.config, and i am using HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress for detection between deployment and development environment:

```
public static SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress != "127.0.0.1")
    ...
    else
    ...
}
```

but problem is here, some times HttpContext.Current is null and raise exception (i.e: when scheduled task is runed in asp.net from global.asax).
is there any general solution for this?

Comment: IsLocal is a method of Request and some times Request is null. the above is not perfect solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're supposed to change the connection string in the configuration file between environments. That's why they're stored in a configuration file in the first place, so you wouldn't have to do this.

I prefer to put connection strings in a separate file and not deploy it at all. The same can be done with other configuration that's environment specific. Another way is to use an XML transform as a part of your build job to change the connection string when deploying into production.

Comment: ok but when we store connection string in web.config, we can use the method that defined in .net framework to read connection string.

Comment: Huh? Isn't that exactly what the configuration files are for? Reading stuff from?

Comment: No, but if exist any solution for web.config, it's better from your solution. your solution is good if there is not any other solution.

Comment: @mmtemporary: I still don't understand what you're trying to ask. Are you asking if you can put connection strings in a separate file and still use `ConfigurationManager` etc to read them? If so, the answer is yes. Google for the standard `configSource` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Matti, use of configSource is good